# How to configure service worker in vitejs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

This is my Vite config:

```js
   VitePWA({
        strategies: 'injectManifest',
        srcDir: 'src',
        filename: 'my-sw.ts',
        injectRegister: 'auto',
        registerType: "autoUpdate",
        workbox: {
          globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html,ico,png,svg}']
        },
        devOptions: {
          enabled: true,
        },

        // TODO: add specific content to align with app requirements.
        manifest: {
         //
        },
      })
```

This is my service worker:

```js
import { precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import { clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";

declare let self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope

self.addEventListener("message", event => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") self.skipWaiting();
});

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
self.skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();
```

Taken from [docs](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/guide/inject-manifest.html#typescript-support).
When I run `npm run build` service worker is copied to public directory. Hence it works as expected, but I don't know how to make app work when offline.

I was trying this [example](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/workbox/inject-manifest.html) but when I go `offline` - it does not seem to work.

What should be done to make app work offline? How I can trigger different service workers events to test and debug it? How to test it in development mode? Could you please point me an appropriate section in documentation? I went through docs but I might miss something.

Comment: "it does not seem to work." You should include all the relevant details so that someone could help you.

Comment: @possum - does not work - means that when offline nothing is shown